# how to modify the combinations table (that made by expand.grid() function) in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations, data-sharing

I made small, reproducible example,
but my real data is really huge...and have lots of levels.

```
roomnumber <- c(1,2,3)

color <- c('red','blue','green')

weight <- c(0.1,0.3,0.5)

data <- expand.grid(roomnumber,color,weight)
names(data) <- c('roomnumber','color','weight')
```

so, the table is as follows.
it contains every combinations.

```
 roomnumber color weight
1           1   red    0.1
2           2   red    0.1
3           3   red    0.1
4           1  blue    0.1
5           2  blue    0.1
6           3  blue    0.1
7           1 green    0.1
8           2 green    0.1
9           3 green    0.1
10          1   red    0.3
11          2   red    0.3
12          3   red    0.3
13          1  blue    0.3
14          2  blue    0.3
15          3  blue    0.3
16          1 green    0.3
17          2 green    0.3
18          3 green    0.3
19          1   red    0.5
20          2   red    0.5
21          3   red    0.5
22          1  blue    0.5
23          2  blue    0.5
24          3  blue    0.5
25          1 green    0.5
26          2 green    0.5
27          3 green    0.5
```

however, in this data, I want something more.
when the "color" variable is "blue",
I want to add more combination

specifically, the weight is either 0.1, 0.3, or 0.5 for this combinations
but when the "color" is "blue", I want a weight to be 0.1, 0.3, 0.5 AND 0.7

```
weight_2 <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7)
```

how do I edit this?

(I can easily do manually with this minimal example, but my real data is so huge that it is hard to do manually)

Comment: `rbind(expand.grid(roomnumber, c("red", "green"), weight), expand.grid(roomnumber, "blue", c(weight, 0.7)))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways, both slightly inefficient (though that may be unavoidable).

1. Add it for all, then remove `0.7` from non-blue rows.

   ```r
   data <- expand.grid(roomnumber = 1:3, color = c("red", "blue", "green"), weight = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7))
   data <- subset(data, color == "blue" | weight != 0.7)
   data
   #    roomnumber color weight
   # 1           1   red    0.1
   # 2           2   red    0.1
   # 3           3   red    0.1
   # 4           1  blue    0.1
   # 5           2  blue    0.1
   # 6           3  blue    0.1
   # 7           1 green    0.1
   # 8           2 green    0.1
   # 9           3 green    0.1
   # 10          1   red    0.3
   # 11          2   red    0.3
   # 12          3   red    0.3
   # 13          1  blue    0.3
   # 14          2  blue    0.3
   # 15          3  blue    0.3
   # 16          1 green    0.3
   # 17          2 green    0.3
   # 18          3 green    0.3
   # 19          1   red    0.5
   # 20          2   red    0.5
   # 21          3   red    0.5
   # 22          1  blue    0.5
   # 23          2  blue    0.5
   # 24          3  blue    0.5
   # 25          1 green    0.5
   # 26          2 green    0.5
   # 27          3 green    0.5
   # 31          1  blue    0.7
   # 32          2  blue    0.7
   # 33          3  blue    0.7
   ```
2. `rbind` the additional blue-only rows.

   ```r
   data <- expand.grid(roomnumber = 1:3, color = c("red", "blue", "green"), weight = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5))
   data <- rbind(data, expand.grid(roomnumber = 1:3, color = "blue", weight = 0.7))
   data
   #    roomnumber color weight
   # 1           1   red    0.1
   # 2           2   red    0.1
   # 3           3   red    0.1
   # 4           1  blue    0.1
   # 5           2  blue    0.1
   # 6           3  blue    0.1
   # 7           1 green    0.1
   # 8           2 green    0.1
   # 9           3 green    0.1
   # 10          1   red    0.3
   # 11          2   red    0.3
   # 12          3   red    0.3
   # 13          1  blue    0.3
   # 14          2  blue    0.3
   # 15          3  blue    0.3
   # 16          1 green    0.3
   # 17          2 green    0.3
   # 18          3 green    0.3
   # 19          1   red    0.5
   # 20          2   red    0.5
   # 21          3   red    0.5
   # 22          1  blue    0.5
   # 23          2  blue    0.5
   # 24          3  blue    0.5
   # 25          1 green    0.5
   # 26          2 green    0.5
   # 27          3 green    0.5
   # 28          1  blue    0.7
   # 29          2  blue    0.7
   # 30          3  blue    0.7
   ```